# rails server just displays help message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to start a rails server using:

- ruby 1.9.3p125
- rails 3.2.2
- windows XP pro sp3

I am following [Getting Started on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

When I attempt to start the server with `rails server` the cli just displays the rails help message.

How can I get past the help message and start the rails server?

Answer (score 3):

You need to be in the app's directory to run `rails server`.

Comment: Yup.  That solved it.  Knew it had to be a rookie moment.  Thanks so much.